# How Sum value of multiple datetime?

Tags: sql

i want sum value of multiple datetime.

**Code**

```
SELECT cs.EmployeeRun, cs.Date, cs.Total, SUM(cs.Total) as Sum
FROM CusSalaryDay cs
WHERE cs.Date Between '2012-12-03' and '2012-12-05'
GROUP BY cs.EmployeeRun, cs.Date, cs.Total
Order By EmployeeRun,Date
```

**Output**

```
EmployeeRun | Date | Total | Sum
2330005 | 2012-12-03 00:00:00.000 | 600 |   600
2330005 | 2012-12-04 00:00:00.000 | 600 |   600
2330005 | 2012-12-05 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 0
3467951 | 2012-12-03 00:00:00.000 | 600 |   600
3467951 | 2012-12-04 00:00:00.000 | 600 |   600
3467951 | 2012-12-05 00:00:00.000 | 480 |   480
```

**But I need output**

```
EmployeeRun | Date | Sum
2330005 | 2012-12-03 - 2012-12-05 | 1200
3467951 | 2012-12-03 - 2012-12-05 | 1680
```

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove `date` and `cs.total` from the `group by` in your query:

```
SELECT cs.EmployeeRun, min(cs.Date) as MinDate, max(cs.Date) as MaxDate,
       SUM(cs.Total) as SumTotal
FROM CusSalaryDay cs
WHERE cs.Date Between '2012-12-03' and '2012-12-05'
GROUP BY cs.EmployeeRun
Order By EmployeeRun
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the flavor of server you're using, but in MySQL you'd just:

```
SELECT
     EmployeeRun,
     Date,
     Total,
     SUM(Total) AS sum
FROM CusSalaryDay
WHERE Date Between
    '2012-12-03'
    AND
    '2012-12-05'
GROUP BY EmployeeRun
Order By
    EmployeeRun,
    Date
```

Formatting aside, just keeping your `GROUP BY` limited to `EmployeeRun`